# Verify proof of $ \left( 1 + \frac{x}{n} \right)^n < e^x \,\text{and} \, e^x < \left(1 - \frac{x}{n}\right)^{-n}$

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, exponential-function, approximation, solution-verification

The following is from Tom Apostol's Calculus I, on page 250, exercise 42.:

If $\mathit{n}$ is a positive integer and if $\mathit{x} > 0$, show that
$$ \left( 1 + \frac{x}{n} \right)^n < e^x \text, \qquad \text{and that} \qquad e^x < \left(1 - \frac{x}{n}\right)^{-n} \quad \text{if} \quad x < n. $$

There is no solution provided in the book, I would like to ask someone to verify if mine is correct:

Integrating the inequality $ 1 > \frac{1}{1 + \frac{x}{n}} $ we get that

$$ \int_0^x{1dt} > \int_0^x{\frac{1}{1 + \frac{t}{n}}dt} \qquad \text{yielding}
\qquad x > n\log\left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right). $$

Since $ e $ is strictly increasing it follows that
$$ e^x > \left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^{n}. $$

Similarly, integrating $ 1 < \frac{1}{1 - \frac{x}{n}} $ we get that
$$ \int_0^x{1dt} < \int_0^x{\frac{1}{1 - \frac{t}{n}}dt} \qquad \text{yielding} \qquad x < -n\log\left(1 - \frac{x}{n}\right) . $$
It follows that
$$ e^x <\left(1 - \frac{x}{n}\right)^{-n} . $$

Comment: Simpler is to note that $e^x\ge1+x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. However, both your derivations look fine.

Comment: Thanks for going through it. Could you explain how we get from your inequality to the ones in the question?

Comment: I have added an answer with some more detail.

Comment: Thanks, that solution looks indeed simpler.

Comment: If you look at Exercise 41 in Apostol, you'll see it asks you to deduce the inequality robjohn cites.

Comment: Yes, which I did. Yet I missed the obvious path... I even wondered how come he didn't provided a hint in the form of a preceding exercise as he usually does. My only excuse may be that I tried hard to reuse the (b)/(c) inequalities in exercise 41. (and succeeded to prove the lower bound inequality using them, but miserably failed to prove the upper bound one) and perhaps forgot about the preceding conclusions in the process. My takeaway is to be able to stop chasing a solution in one direction and step back to see if there is something obvious missed.

Comment: @ImreDeák, it's always good to step back and look for what you might have overlooked, but actually I find a lot to like in the approach you took to proving the inequalities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your proofs look fine.

Another approach is to use the fact that $e^x\ge1+x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, with strict inequality for $x\ne0$. This follows from the strict convexity of $e^x-1-x$ and its minimum of $0$ at $x=0$.

Then we have for $x\gt0$,
$$
e^{x/n}\gt1+\frac xn\implies e^x\gt\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n\tag{1}
$$
and
$$
e^{-x/n}\gt1-\frac xn\implies e^x\lt\left(1-\frac xn\right)^{-n}\tag{2}
$$
Inequality $(2)$ does rely on the fact that $x\lt n$ so that the quantity being raised to the negative power is positive.